# Why has AFL been removed from the repositories in 19.10?

Tags: 19.10

Ubuntu has included an AFL package at least since 16.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&searchon=names&keywords=afl

However, I was surprised to discover that it is no longer present in 19.10. The last version with the package appears to be 19.04, see link above. I've tried searching for reasons for removal, but without much success. There is nothing on discourse.ubuntu.com or bugs.ubuntu.com.

I'm curious to know why Ubuntu no longer provides prebuilt packages for AFL.

Comment: It may have been replaced by afl++  (at least in focal; https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/afl++ https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=afl) ; it's also from a new person, and being a 'universe' or community supported package; maybe that's why....

Comment: @guiverc The old package tracked the debian package: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/afl/tree/debian/master, the new one comes from a github fork: https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/AFLplusplus. It feels like an odd direction, usually packages from Debian had a simple way into ubuntu. Good to know a replacement is coming back though!

Comment: A *large* number of 'universe' packages come from github sources; LXQt used by Lubuntu for example comes direct from github and not debian, and that's just one example.